# Can I use a single line or column of an 2-dimensional array as a single-dimensional array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, parameters

I am trying to pass a single line of a 2-d array to a function. However, I don't want to copy its contents to a separate 1-d array and use the latter as a parameter, but rather use the line (or column) itself. Is there a way to do this in C?

Comment: Which one shall it be, the column or the row? One is easy, the other does not work.

Comment: Seems I have no choice. The easy one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int* array, int size) {
    // Print the contents of 1-D array.
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("arr[%d]: %d\n", i, array[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    // Create a 2-D array consisting of two 1-D arrays as its elements:
    // - First array elements: 0, 1
    // - Second array elements: 2, 3
    int arr[2][2] = { {0, 1}, {2, 3} };

    // Print the first 1-D array.
    printArray(arr[0], 2);

    // Print the second 1-D array.
    printArray(arr[1], 2);
}
```